# Running idf.py runconfig only opens the "idf.py" file in vscode

Tags: python, vscode-extensions, esp-idf

I installed the ESP-idf extension "express install"
idf.py is not recognized so

[image]

i added manually the environment variables IDF_PATH, IDF_TOOLS_PATH and also added %IDF_PATH%/tools to the Path variable.

[image]

Now when I run "idf.py menuconfig" in vs code terminal it just opens the idf.py file in vs code

[image]

[image]

What i am doing wrong.
Also if I run python "$env:IDF_TOOLS_PATH\idf.py" menuconfig i get the following

Python 3.10.8

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fix (for me): Open vsc from powershell rather than git bash

I had the same issue. I was opening vsc from git bash using the following:

```bash
cd ./project-directory
code .
```

Then I'd run espressif's esp-idf terminal (using powershell default profile)
This caused the same/similar issue as you had.

The fix (for me) was to stop calling vsc from git bash, and rather call it from powershell

Perhaps someone else can shed some light on why this is, my guess is that git bash vs powershell will call vsc with either different arguments, or perhaps give it different permissions?